# Simple Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solving Partial Differential Equation $x f_{y}+y f_{x} =0$ ?

$f=f(x,y)$ is a real-valued function of two variables $x,y$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The equation is separable. Write $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$, so that $f_x=g'h$ and $f_y=g\dot h$. Then you have $$xg(x)\dot h(y) +yg'(x)h(y)=0$$

Divide both sides by $xygh$ and move one term to the other side to get $$\frac{\dot h(y)}{yh(y)} =- \frac{g'(x)}{xg(x)}$$
Now separate the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the chain rule to rewrite the equation in terms of the new variables $u=x$, $v=x^2-y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I would search method of characteristics. If you use that method the differential relation is

$$\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{df}{0}$$

$$ydy=xdx$$

So there are two invariants along the characteristics

$$y^2-x^2$$

And $f$ itself, so we set one constant equal to a function of the other constant

$$f(x,y)=\varphi(y^2-x^2)$$

Now plug this back into the original 1st order PDE to show for yourself that this solution is correct.